# highlight error cell or input when validation fails in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jqgrid inline editing  with validation in grid using edit rules . i want to add  class  to highlight errors(eg: ui-state-error) for the input which fails in validation .
i can set class to highlight  error using this

*jQuery('#'+grid_id).jqGrid('setCell',row_id,errfields[a],'','ui-state-error',{color: 'blue'});*

But it is not working in jqgrid when inbuilt validation fails .
How do i highlight the validation error triggered cell/input  .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithInlineEditing.htm) shows how the probelm can be solved:

[image]

In the demo the columns "Amount", "Tax" and "Total" will be validated with the following validation rule:

```
editrules:{required:true,number:true}
```

On any validation error the first input field where the validation failed dditional class "ui-state-error" will be added. It is the standard jQuery UI CSS class. Addionally I set focus to the input field.

For the implementation I overwride (chain) the default implementation of the methods `$.jgrid.checkValues` and `$.jgrid.hideModal`. Here is the corresponding code:

```
var grid = $("#list");
grid.jqGrid({
    // define all jqGrid options
});

var originalCheckValues = $.jgrid.checkValues,
    originalHideModal = $.jgrid.hideModal,
    iColWithError = 0;
$.jgrid.checkValues = function(val, valref,g, customobject, nam) {
    var tr,td,
        ret = originalCheckValues.call(this,val, valref,g, customobject, nam);
    if (!ret[0]) {
        tr = g.rows.namedItem(editingRowId);
        if (tr) {
            $(tr).children('td').children('input.editable[type="text"]').removeClass("ui-state-error");
            iColWithError = valref; // save to set later the focus
            //error_td_input_selector = 'tr#'+editingRowId+' > td:nth-child('+(valref+1)+') > input.editable[type="text"]:first';
            td = tr.cells[valref];
            if (td) {
                $(td).find('input.editable[type="text"]').addClass("ui-state-error");
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
};
$.jgrid.hideModal = function (selector,o) {
    var input, oldOnClose, td,
        tr = grid[0].rows.namedItem(editingRowId);
    if (tr) {
        td = tr.cells[iColWithError];
        if (td) {
            input = $(td).children('input.editable[type="text"]:first');
            if (input.length > 0) {
                oldOnClose = o.onClose;
                o.onClose = function(s) {
                    if ($.isFunction(oldOnClose)) {
                        oldOnClose.call(s);
                    }
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        input.focus();
                    },100);
                };
            }
        }
    }
    originalHideModal.call(this,selector,o);
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .The ans is very helpful . do i need to repeat '$.jgrid.checkValues' and '$.jgrid.hideModal' functions in each grid , if i have more that two editable grid in a page .

Comment: @Shermi: The `$`, `$.jgrid` are global objects which belongs to the `window` object. So the full name of `$.jgrid.checkValues` and `$.jgrid.hideModal` is `window.$.jgrid.checkValues` and `window.$.jgrid.hideModal`. In other words the function `checkValues` and `hideModal` belong not the instance of the grid and thus should be reimplemented **only once**.

Comment: @Oleg: When using the above code for overriding the checkValues method I am getting "too much recursion" error on Firefox console for this line    ret = originalCheckValues.call(this,val, valref,g, customobject, nam);

Comment: @RRK: [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithInlineEditing.htm) which I posted don't have the described problem. So I suppose that there are problem in **your code**. For example you inserted the code which I suggested more as one times.

Comment: @Oleg: Thank you. I had inserted the above code outside the document.ready(); method and hence the error. After I placed the code inside the ready() method I no longer get the recursion error. In addition to highlighting the cell, i was able to add a qtip error message on the cell. I would now like to disable the popup dialog with the error message that jqgrid displays. Any ideas?

Comment: I checked your other post on how to override jQuery.jgrid.info_dialog and was able to not display the popup. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @Oleg for the great work. You have been such a great help in the jqgrid forums.

Answer (score 0):

In my project, I combine to use jqgrid and [jquery validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) to examine and highlight errors, to provide unified look and feel in the entire application. You can use `rowId_columnName` as id to find the editor (input, select, etc.), e.g. `$('#1_name')` for name column in row 1 and then use the jquery object to add a rules, e.g. `$('#1_name').rules('add', {required:true})` to add a rule to enforce that the cell is required, then calling `$('#1_name').valid()` to force a validation pass when value is submitted, e.g. before calling jqgrid `saveRow` method. Open the link for the plugin to know more about rules method and valid method.

Comment: can you help me in this regard by having a look at [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064210/how-to-use-jquery-validate-js-to-validate-cells-in-jqgrid#comment17744539_13064210)