# Jqgrid with keyboad navigation with multiselect:true

Tags: jqgrid

hi i am using jqgrid and want to do something like if i set multiselect:true and also set keyboard navigation. then my grid should work both functionality. 
Can any one tell me how to do that.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jqGrid have till now very restricted support of the keyboard navigation. The current implementation of [bindKeys](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods#configuring_jqgrid_to_use_only_the_new_api) don't support `multiselect:true` option.

One possible implementation of `bindKeys` which supports `multiselect:true` I posed in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6170308/315935). I can warn you that the suggestion solution was only quick & dirty way to have keyboard support in case of `multiselect:true`. The better would be to use some key like <kbd>Space</kbd> key to select the row and use <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> to change the focus only *without* selection of the rows. One could use `ui-state-focus` and `ui-state-hover` to mark the row which has the focus instead of selection the row.