# jqGrid - Keyboard navigation with multiselect turned on

Tags: jqgrid

I need the ability to navigate the data within the jqGrid. I have virtual paging turned on scroll = 1 and multiselect turned on.
I need the ability to use keyboard arrows keys, page-up, page-down, home, end button.
Page up and Page down to move between pages and home to go to the first page and end to the last page in the jqGrid.
Anyone who has done this or how this can be done would be most appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear *how* keyboard navigation should work in case of `multiselect: true`. You can find some old suggestion (which is far to be perfect) in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6170308/315935). I think that good implementation of keyboard navigation should include keyboard navigation which change the focus of the row only and not change the selection. Another key, like space, should be used to select or unselect rows. Additional work should be done to implement selection of the ranges of rows (with the usage of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> for example).

Comment: tried this code works fine but I have a slight issue. My kepress handler works only one time and second time I click any key designated in code I cant hit the breakpoints. Any clues why this would be happening

Comment: @chugh97: Sorry, but I don't understand what you do. Which version of jqGrid you use? Which code you executed? Which keys in which order one should press to reproduce the problem which you describe? Which breakpoint you mean? Is the problem exist only if you set breakpoint or you can reproduce (describe) the problem without setting any breakpoints?