# How to show all form errors together in jqGrid?

Tags: jqgrid

When there are any errors in 'edit' or 'add' form, errors are shown one by one on top with red background. Is there some variable which could be set to show all errors together? I couldn't find any such setting.

[This question was also asked on the jqGrid forum](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules), but it isn't answered yet. (Last comment by David, 2011/03/17 08:52 )

**Edit:**

When I click on "edit", a form is opened. Suppose there are few "required" fields on that form and I leave them all empty. Now when I press "submit" button on form, only error about the first "required" field is shown, not for all the required fields. When I rectify first required field and press submit again, only then it tells about second required field. I want to show all errors about required fields once and together. I hope that clarifies the question.

Comment: Could you explain what you want more exactly? One can't open "Edit" and "Add" forms at the same time. So why should be displayed all errors which where time time before? Why it can be better as standard pop-up with the current error only?

Comment: @Oleg: kindly see my edit for clarifications.

Comment: Now I understand your question. I find it good. Unfortunately the behavier of jqGrid is so that it search for the first validation error and brake the validation process. Probably using `beforeCheckValues` one can change the behavior. I will think about the problem and what can be done. Look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988767/highlight-error-cell-or-input-when-validation-fails-in-jqgrid/6162086#6162086) at the begining. I will try to add 'ui-state-error' class to all invalid fields, set focuk on the first field having the error and create the full error message.