# jqGrid - multiple validation of fields

Tags: jquery, validation, jqgrid

I am trying to validate multiple date fields similar to how it is being done on

[jqGrid - Validation of fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398581/jqgrid-validation-of-fields)

I followed the example ran into an issue with the user being able to select multiple fields in that they were still editable but not being put back into display mode after another field is selected.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue which you describe is connected only with the implementation of inline editing and not with the validation of multiple fields.

Look at [another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/2filedsvalidation2.htm) which use the same validation, but which fixes the described problem.

Comment: Howdy Oleg, if I enter a value in for 2 fields, I get an error. I then fix it to where there is a value in one or the other. If I click on another field, I still get the error again.

Comment: @WebDev: Thanks! Now I see my error. Please try again, I hope that I fixed the problem. The code is not elegant of cause but it should work.