# JqGrid not highlight error when editing validation fails

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I use inline edit mode with some editrules (editrules:{number:true} for example).

When I save, if the validation fails the errror message box appeart correctly but the faultly field is not highlighted in red (class ui-state-error).

By default, should not jqgrid added the class "ui-state-error" ?

```
grid.jqGrid({
    datatype: 'local',
    data: colD.rootVar,
    gridview: true,
    colModel : [
        {name: "Team", label:"team", index:"team", width:"150", align:"center", sortable:false},
        {name:"Employee", index:"employee", width:"150", align:"center", sortable:false},
        {name:"col_01", index:"1", width:"50", align:"center", sortable:false, editable:true, editrules:{required: true, number:true} },
        {name:"col_02", index:"2", width:"50", align:"center", sortable:false, editable:true } ],
    pager: jQuery('#pager'),
    rowNum: 20,
    rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
    height: "auto",
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: "Planning Management ITEC-PRD"
    });

    grid.jqGrid('navGrid',"#pager",{edit:false, add:false, del:false});
    grid.jqGrid('inlineNav',"#pager",{edit:true, add:false, del:false});
}
```

Thx for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can follow my suggestion from [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6162086/315935). How shows [the modified demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithInlineEditing_.htm) of the old code works with the current version jqGrid 4.4.5 too.

Comment: Sorry Oleg, I don't know how I could missed your old answer ! :/ Thx

Comment: @bigburgr: You are welcome! The less is voting counter of the answer the more difficult one can find it. Best wishes!