# (jqgrid) highlight cell with validation error and keep the row in edit mode till validation error exists

Tags: jqgrid

I looked at all the relevant examples, but haven't found a solution yet that would work for me. I want the cell to be highlighted if it has validation error. I tried the a solution 
from stackoverflow that makes use of `checkValues` but it didnt work as in the following

`$.jgrid.checkValues = function(val, valref, g, customobject, nam)`

`g`, `customobject` and `nam` are undefined and I can't figure out what these parameters are for.

My validation is calculation based, so I tried custom function in the edit rules. It works, but I don't want a popup dialog, I want to highlight the cell with validation error.

Comment: Can you add the link to the SO question you are talking about

Comment: Adding the link to [resolution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988767/highlight-error-cell-or-input-when-validation-fails-in-jqgrid/6162086#6162086) so others can find it .

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the example but I have the snippet from that answer

```
 var originalCheckValues = $.jgrid.checkValues,
            originalHideModal = $.jgrid.hideModal,
            iColWithError = 0;
       $.jgrid.checkValues = function(val, valref, g, customobject, nam) {
            var tr, td,
                ret = originalCheckValues.call(this, val, valref, g, customobject, nam);
            if (!ret[0]) {
                tr = g.rows.namedItem(lastSel);
                if (tr) {
                    $(tr).children('td').children('input.editable[type="text"]').removeClass("ui-state-error");
                    iColWithError = valref; // save to set later the focus
                    td = tr.cells[valref];
                    if (td) {
                        $(td).find('input.editable[type="text"]').addClass("ui-state-error");
                    }
                }
            }
            return ret;
        };
```

Comment: Hi Oleg, this snippet is from the your answer to that post. Was wondering if you could help me with this question.