# jqGrid Highlight error cell when validation fails

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-inlinenav

I am using jqgrid 4.6. I tried implementing the  code give in the link below to highlight error cell. But I get error 'Unable to get property 'rows' of undefined or null reference'. Can you please help me resolve it. Thanks!

Link:[Oleg's answer in Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988767/highlight-error-cell-or-input-when-validation-fails-in-jqgrid)

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a bit late but here it is:

using version 4.6 this bit of code:

```
$.jgrid.checkValues = function(val, valref, g, customobject, nam)
```

This is no longer working, somehow the `g` is undefined.

You'll need to change this line of code: (in Oleg's answer)

From:

```
 if (!ret[0]) {

   tr = g.rows.namedItem(editingRowId);
```

to:

```
if (!ret[0]) {

  tr = grid[0].rows.namedItem(editingRowId); //line 95 of original code
```

This should work.