# highlight error on input form when validation fails in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am interested with highlight error on input when validation fails in jqgrid.

I found some discussions here
[highlight error cell or input when validation fails in jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988767/highlight-error-cell-or-input-when-validation-fails-in-jqgrid)

But i need to highlight error  on input form not inline editing.

Could you guide me how to do that, please?

Regards,

Candra

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used?

Comment: I use jqgrid free 4.7

Comment: The free-jqgrid as I know stopped its development and support before 3 years. Not sure if it support html5 checking. You can switch to Guriddo jqGrid and use html5 stuff, which is exqactly what you want. See [demo here](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/edit_add_delete/dialog_html5/index.html)

Comment: Ok. I will try it